# Are there complex numbers whose sines are zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I recently learned that $\sin(z)$ has an extension into the complex plane, namely:

$$\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

Is there any complex number $z=a+bi$, with $b≠0$ such that $\sin(z)=0$ ?

I am already aware of the 'trivial' zeros when $a=πk$ with $k\in\Bbb Z$ and $b=0$.

Is there any way to prove this? Either complete solutions/proofs or hints would both be helpful.

Comment: There are no more zeros, but you can simply compute $\sin(a+ib)$ using the formula and see at what you arrive.

Comment: Note that if $w$ has a real component then $|e^w|\neq |e^{-w}|$.

Comment: Thanks these answer my question. I kept making a silly mistake with the exponentials.

Comment: By the way, note that on the reals, the $\sin$ function is bounded ($|\sin x|\le1$), but it's unbounded on the complex numbers. There's a theorem that says that _no_ differentiable, nonconstant function is bounded on the complex numbers. ("Differentiable" is actually a fairly strong criterion for complex functions, by the way; for example, $|z|$ and ${\rm Im}(z)$ are not differentiable at _any_ point. This is partly because the $h$ in the expression $\lim_{h\to0}$, in the definition of the derivative, is now allowed to be a _complex_ number approaching $0$ from any direction in the plane.)

Comment: Maybe of interest http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941036/the-zeros-of-sinz-where-z-is-a-complex-number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the lovely trigonometrical identity
$$ \lvert \sin{(x+iy)} \rvert^2 = \sin^2{x}+\sinh^2{y} $$
(use the angle-addition formulae, the relationships between the trigonometric and hyperbolic functions, and the Pythagorean identity): since $\sinh^2{y}>0$ unless $y=0$, the only zeros occur when $y=0$ and $x$ is a root of $\sin$, i.e. the usual real ones.